# GWT: how can I trigger resize of one child, if another one was updated, container remains unchanged?

Tags: java, gwt, resize

I have two widgets, placed into container. This looks like a mainScreenWidget and footerWidget. Together they should be spread through the all space.

Imagine the size of footerWidget changes due to changing its contents. This event should be propagated to main widget because it has some complicated calculations based on size.

A question is: how can I do it?

```
<container>
  <mainWidget/> - its needs two know about footers size: the two widgets should be spread all over the container
  <footerWidget/> - its size can be changed: second line can be added etc
</container>
```

In my case widgets are stored in a div-based table, buts thats not the case:

```
<div style="display:table">
<div style="display:table-row"><div style="display:table-cell" class="mainWidget">...
<div style="display:table-row"><div style="display:table-cell" class="footerWidget">...
</div>
```

Comment: GWT provides layout panels for this. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options:

1. Use LayoutPanel with two layers - one for main widget, one for footer widget.
2. Use CSS. For example, you can position your footer absolutely and let the browser resize the main widget.